# Youtube API calls from PHP Code Igniter framework to get the last videos from a specific Youtube user

Tags: php, codeigniter, youtube

Can anybody help me out with some code sample? I found out [**this example**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#retrieve_my_uploads), but I don't know from where to get the `$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID` and `$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET`. From Youtube API I get a key (as in a certificate), is this the `$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET` and I should use it as a string?

Comment: Did you try searching Google? First result:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application

Comment: I did that, that's why I said that I got a key (certificate) and I don't know how should I use it in their example code...